Why is Howard Hamlin so interested in hiring Jimmy even after knowing all of what Chuck proved about him?
Why is Howard so interested hiring Jimmy in spite of all he knew about him in regards to Chuck’s apparently proven accusations of felony misconduct?
Why would Hamlin simply forget all that in light of Jimmy serving on the board of the charity?
Chuck’s allegations were confessed to by Jimmy, and he witnessed Jimmy attempt to cover it up… all huge problems for a lawyer…
It’s even revealed later on, that Howard knows it was Jimmy throwing bowling balls into his car...

Read all of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Hamlin#Character_biography .

It doesn’t explain any reason why Howard would suddenly change his position on Jimmy’s employment…

Interested in hiring him, when exactely?

Howard does not care if his lawyers are dirty. Howard did a lot to placate Chuck and exploit his talents, and ironically it would turn out that Chuck's talents involve many underhanded tactics that carefully toe the legal line. For example in Chicanery, Chuck insists "I didn't entrap you. I provoked an admission in adverse interest. That's not the same thing." He is making a legal distinction to distract from his unethical actions; his scheming combined with his deep-seated grudge and untreated mental illness is why the bar association shows incredible lenience toward Jimmy. Jimmy's scheming is a familiar perk, not a downside.
The McGill wiles aren't the only reason. Howard witnessed and admired Jimmy's earnest advocacy of a student, which echoed the tough encouragement Jimmy gave Howard at his lowest moment a year prior. It would also be a righting of a wrong; now that Chuck isn't there to sabotage, Howard can finally hire a very cunning and motivated lawyer.
Howard made the mistake of thinking Jimmy was healthy enough to move on from his exclusion from HHM and Chuck's suicide. He never understood the true significance of Jimmy working at HHM with his brother, so he thoughtlessly extended what he thought was an olive branch and a chance to revitalize HHM with another Hamlin-McGill leadership. He does rescind it over the bowling balls and the hookers.

Great response.  I missed some of these nuances when I watched BCS.
